# How to calculate age in python from a file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Here's how my file looks like

Name  Gender Birth Death
John  Male   1940  1990
Steve Male  1953  1985
John  Male  1933  1965
Sara  Female 1917 1955

I have tried these methods and getting some errors.

```
file = pd.read_csv('file')

df.insert(6, "Age", file['Death - Birth'])
age = pd.Series([])
```

and

```
for i in range(len(df)):
age[i] = df['Death Year - Birth Year']
```

I want to add a age column which would calculate the age based on birth and death year.

Comment: What errors are you getting? Please include **all** relevant code and data, as well as an explanation of your debugging efforts. See: [mcve], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/11301900, https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Comment: I would recommend reading the Pandas docs, your code is unidiomatic and could be simplified drastically thanks to some knowledge of the library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should be a simple fix:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')

df['age'] = df['death'] - df['birth']
```